# createAbsoluteUrl generates a path-like URL, how to avoid it?

Tags: php, url, yii

I create a URL like this:

```
$app->createAbsoluteUrl('/', array(
     'param1' => 'val1',
     'param2' => 'var2',
);
```

The generated URL is:

```
http://mysite.com/param1/var1/param2/var2
```

But I expect a url like this:

```
http://mysite.com/?param1=var1&param2=var2
```

In function [manual](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#createAbsoluteUrl-detail) it says:

> $params   array   additional GET parameters (name=>value). Both the name and value will be URL-encoded.

But it doesn't seem to work like that. How I can generate the expected URL? Thanks.

Comment: The params are URL encoded... try using 'test var' instead of 'var1' and you'll see. It's just not the approach you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify that the [`urlManager`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUrlManager) application component should use the "get" format for the URLs it generates; the default is to use the "path" format. The Yii guide [explains](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#creating-urls) how to do it inside your application configuration:

```
array(
    ......
    'components'=>array(
        ......
        'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'get',
        ),
    ),
);
```

**Update:** So your `urlFormat` is "path" and that's by design... what about alternatives?

If you don't mind extending `CWebApplication` and using your own derived class in its place then you have several options such as:

1. Define your own `createUrlEx` method based on the original `createUrl`. It could look like this:

   ```
   public function createUrlEx($format,$route,$params=array(),$ampersand='&')
   {
       $oldFormat = $this->getUrlManager()->getUrlFormat();
       $this->getUrlManager()->setUrlFormat($format);
       $url = $this->getUrlManager()->createUrl($route,$params,$ampersand);
       $this->getUrlManager()->setUrlFormat($oldFormat);
       return $url;
   }
   ```
2. Override [`registerCoreComponents`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebApplication#registerCoreComponents-detail) so that you can have a second url manager:

   ```
   protected function registerCoreComponents()
   {
       parent::registerCoreComponents();

       $components=array(
           'specialUrlManager'=>array(
               'class'=>'CUrlManager',
               'urlFormat'=>'get',
           ),
       );

       $this->setComponents($components);
   }
   ```

   You can now call `Yii::app()->specialUrlManager->createUrl(...)` anytime.

You can also approach the problem in other ways:

1. Extend `CUrlManager` and expose a method that allows you to select the flavor of url to create on the spot.
2. If you only need "get" urls in one or two places, you can always create a new `CUrlManager` object, configure it on the spot, call `createUrl` and then discard it. You could also hide this ugliness behind a free function. Essentially this (admittedly *not recommended*) approach is a low-tech version of the first workaround given that has the advantage that you don't need to extend `CWebApplication`.

Comment: I know it, my urlFormat is 'path', I need it. But for some case I need to generate links like http://mysite.com/some/path/?get=params . Obviously I can add it simply by $url .= '?get=params'; but its bad solution I think.

Comment: @FelikZ: I updated the answer, have a look at some alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use something like `Yii::app()->urlManager->createPathInfo` This will generate the query string as ...&var=val&... using a custom `&` and `=` if you like. You could use this to create a query string version of a URL on demand with:

```
$url = $this->createAbsoluteUrl('/').'index.php?'.Yii::app()->urlManager->createPathInfo($arrayOfStuff);
```

Or you might even be able to do:

```
Yii::app()->urlManager->urlFormat = 'get';
$this->createAbsoluteUrl('My/Path');
Yii::app()->urlManager->urlFormat = 'path';
```

Although I haven't and don't want to test the second method.

Comment: This is very useful too, 10x.

Answer (score 0):

URL route should be in the format of 'ControllerID/ActionID'. [manual](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication#createAbsoluteUrl-detail)

Your manual link is for CController and isn't for CApplication.